# JQuery each loop problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have the following code

```
  <div>
 <a href="#" class="clickMe">test</a>
 <ul>
     <li class="action_li">1</li>
     <li class="action_li">2</li>
 </ul></div> <div>
 <a href="#" class="clickMe">test</a>
 <ul>
     <li class="action_li">3</li>
     <li class="action_li">4</li>
 </ul>
```

and I want to loop on all the `<li>` that are enclosed with the same `<div>` as the clicked `<a>`

```
$("a.clickMe").live("click", function(eve){
   eve.preventDefault();
   $('.action_li').each(function(index) {
      console.debug(this);
   }); 
});
```

but of course this will get me all the 4 `<li>` not the two enclosed
so I want to have something that starts with `$(this)` and ends with `.each()`

Comment: **I want to have something that starts with `$(this)` and ends with `.each()`**.  Is there a particular reason for this constraint (seems kind of arbitrary)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("a.clickMe").live("click", function(eve){
   eve.preventDefault();
   $('.action_li', $(this).parent()).each(function(index) {
      console.debug(this);
   }); 
});
```

Second parameter next to the selector will limit the search to only part of the DOM tree, in this part to the one `div` which is parent for `a` element.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways, examples:

```
   $(this).parent().find("li.action_li").each(function(index) {
      console.debug(this);
   });
```

or:

```
   $(this).next("ul").children("li.action_li").each(function(index) {
      console.debug(this);
   });
```

etc.

Comment: +1, see http://jsfiddle.net/buMsx/ for the top one working. I'm not quick enough on the draw :)

Comment: it wouldn't work for sure as each() can't work after find().
find by itself would return one element only

Comment: @bhefny - sorry, but that's not correct. find will return as many elements as are matched by the passed selector.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the `<ul>` element that is a sibling of the `<a>`, then get its children.

For example:

```
$(this).siblings('ul').children('li.action_li').each(function(index) {
    //...
});
```

You could also call `$(this).next()` or `$(this).nextAll('ul')`.

Comment: I think you can just use '.action_li' instead of 'li.action_li' or just plain 'li'... it's faster for jquery's selector engine

Comment: @ricecake5: Yes, you can.  However, there might be other `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
$(this).parents('div').find('li').each(...
```